# How to print second to last item in enumeration?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am printing the last item in a list that I enumerate.
How can I also print the second to last item?

```
import itertools

mylist = itertools.cycle(["Blue", "Green", "Red"])

current_number = 14

for num, item in enumerate(mylist, 1):
    print (num, item)
    if num >= (current_number):
        print(item)
        break
```

Prints:

```
(1, 'Blue')
(2, 'Green')
(3, 'Red')
(4, 'Blue')
(5, 'Green')
(6, 'Red')
(7, 'Blue')
(8, 'Green')
(9, 'Red')
(10, 'Blue')
(11, 'Green')
(12, 'Red')
(13, 'Blue')
(14, 'Green')
Green
```

The last item is green.  I want to also print the second to last item which would be Blue in this case.

Is there a clean way to print both the last and second to last in the same if statement?

Comment: Change `current_number` to 13?

Comment: don't shadow `list`. All the answers followed that mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the previous item

```
prev = None
for num, item in enumerate(list, 1):
    print(num, item)
    if num >= current_number:
        print(item, prev)  # -> Green Blue
        break
    prev = item  # For next iteration
```

By the way, `list` is a bad variable name since it shadows the builtin `list` type.

Comment: I like this.  I'm confused how print(item, prev) automatically pulls the previous item.

Comment: @Kade Cause of the `prev = item` at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

When `num == current_number - 1` you should print the element without breaking.

```
for num, item in enumerate(list, 1):
    print (num, item)
    if num == current_number - 1:
        print(item)
    elif num == current_number:
        print(item)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Add each item to a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) limited to two items then print the deque when the condition is satisfied.

```
import collections
stuff = collections.deque(maxlen=2)
for num, item in enumerate(mylist, 1):
    print (num, item)
    stuff.append(item)
    if num >= (current_number):
        print(stuff)
        break
```